# vagrantコマンドをpowershellエイリアスに登録したが使用不可？

Tags: vagrant, powershell

**環境**

- windows10
- vagrant
- virtualbox

vagrant upと毎回うつのがだるいのでpowershellのエイリアスに登録しましたが、vuとうっても認識してくれませんでした。get-aliasでvuが設定されているのは確認しています。

aliasはあるけど認識してないです。powershellのaliasをvagrantコマンドと認識させる方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**自己解決**

new-moduleを利用する

new-moduleはpowershellのコマンド

あとは調べればわかる

Answer (score 1):

PowerShellのaliasには引数を指定する機能はありません。具体的には[New-Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-alias?view=powershell-5.1)は

```
New-Alias
   [-Name] <String>
   [-Value] <String>
   [-Description <String>]
   [-Option <ScopedItemOptions>]
   [-PassThru]
   [-Scope <String>]
   [-Force]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

という構文になっています。`New-Alias vu vagrant up`は

```
New-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'up'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Alias vu vagrant up
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewAliasCommand
```

というエラーになるはずです。